# How can I extend the TRY/CATCH to handle Regular Expression Errors

Tags: c#, regex, error-handling, bots, try-catch

I am writing a BOT that uses a lot of Regular Expressions, sometimes to get one piece of information, depending on the HTML (it gets randomised to stop people like me from finding what I want and taking it ... ) so I will go through a number of regular expressions to obtain X or Y piece of data, such as a name, score, size, weight etc etc.

Is there a way of extending the TRY/CATCH handler so that if it fails on a Regular Expression I have a catch block just for that which would let me log the expression, the HTML I was looking at, and other info without throwing the error.

It's just I have a lot of regular expressions and I don't want to set global flags before the regex execution so that if it fails in the catch, I check the global flag and if true, I know it was a regex that was being executed, so I can then log different info than if something else might have triggered it.

Or you may say that is the best way rather than overriding system code etc.

I have just come out of hospital - again, I do believe I was in there this time last year and not a single power shower on the ward worked, anyway the morphine they have given me is pretty strong so please don't blame me for a stupid question as I would have probably searched a lot more for an answer before asking for help. I am thinking that the flag way is the best way forward rather than extending code I probably shouldn't be but maybe there is already a RegEx failure catch I've missed. #

If I go the flag way I can put a generic error handler in the catch block that checks for that flag and if it finds it logs the regex, html and x y z all in my log file rather than throwing the error which I would do for other errors but with this I want a detailed error report in my log file.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Regex syntax errors throw `ArgumentException` and you can catch that at the `new` expression with a small try/catch block. HOWEVER, don't allow user-provided expressions; every expression you use should be syntactically correct because you wrote and tested them yourself. You should never get this exception once development is complete. Not matching the pattern is not an exception; it's a property on the `Match` class. What exception are you expecting and for what reason?

Comment: The exceptions I am expecting are when the HTML I am using the RegEx on changes making the regex fail. Sometimes parts of the regex come from my DB like names of places that are inserted into the expression e.g regex = @"<span class="town_+?[\s\S}+?>" + town + @"</span>"; so I am never letting users define a regex as its all my code the only thing that may change is the HTML I am using it on - so, therefore, I am thinking now, that maybe no exception is thrown just matches=0 and that is what I want to catch when a working regex suddenly stops due to a change in HTML.

Comment: `Regex`'s `Match()` returns a `Match` object, which has an `IsSuccess` property. That will be `false` if the input does not match the pattern. The `Matches()` method returns a `MatchCollection` object, which will be empty if no matches were found. They do not throw exceptions when the pattern is not matched.

Comment: With that said, you should be treating HTML as markup and parsing it as such, not using Regex. The same advice is given repeatedly on SO, and this is no different. Regex just isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: So my question really should have been can I extend Try/Catch at all to add a catch in where matches = 0 catch(CustomMatchException ex){ this.LastErrorMessage = "A failure occurred in the expression " + regex + " due to a change in the HTML: " + html; this.HelperLib.LogMsg(this.LastErrorMessage); if(this.ThrowOnRegExErr){ throw new System.Exception(this.LastErrorMessage, new System.Exception(regex));} // othwerwise we just let it be logged and increment an error counter err++; }finally{ // or should I put it in here e.g if(throwOnRegEx && RegexErr){ throw( custom exception etc ) } make sense?

Comment: Meanwhile, if you're getting exceptions, it's because you're not creating valid expressions, which is a consequence of not using validated expressions, and instead constructing them from arbitrary data from the database.

Comment: If `IsSuccess` is `false` or the collection's `Count` is `0`, throw your own exception. But why throw an exception? It's not an exceptional condition.

Comment: But no, you can't have a try/catch just suck up some arbitrary condition.

Comment: Frankly, your design warrants complete overhaul based on what what you've explained.

Comment: But not all HTML is HTML is it, most pages nowadays are full off lots of JS that loads in other JS code. I am extracting sections of JS code, then finding parts I need as not all is in the HTML, plus under all these HTML parsers there has to be a string parser somewhere deep down, which probably uses regex anyway, people just think as there is an object XML.parse(xmldoc), that its a magic XML parser but someone had to write a string parser that sits beneath it parsing all the XML these are just objects built ontop to simplyfy the calls.

Comment: I really wanted to "create" a custom exception for when NO MATCHES are found as it would make it easier with current code to throw an error or return one to the calling method than either an error OR a zero match result. I cannot post code here as a) too long and won't let me and b) just a snippet is not enough to understand but it is basically making a custom exception if possible - and I dont know if that is possible, possible & a bad idea, or possible and a good idea if used correctly. I just like experimenting with stuff obviously, so knowing how to do things help. I think a custom handler

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from creating a custom exception. Test the appropriate property depending on which method you're calling and which object it returns, and throw your own. You can do that. That doesn't extend try/catch, though, as your question asks. It just *uses* try/catch with a custom exception.

Comment: would be better, and I can just put in the finally block if no matches found = error, and log without throwing anything, but besides all that a) u dont know the code, b) it is too long to post c) it works except when the source HTML changes which they do a lot, and d) I wanted to know if creating custom exceptions were possible as I like knowing things. If you want me to overhaul over 10,000 lines of code that took over a yr to write the answer is no, its a simple problem and a simple answer, just would like know if it was possible to do that is all. The finally approcach with a flag is better

Comment: You might also consider using Selenium WebDriver so you can interact with a live DOM. The headless (no UI) browser allows JavaScript to run and manipulate nodes dynamically as it would when user is browsing it, and then you can query the DOM structure from your code.

Comment: With these flags, I think you're making things more complicated than they have to be. It sounds like you have lengthy, monolithic code instead of small, well-factored methods.

Comment: Well my BOT is working fine at the moment its just they randomise class names and IDs and put junk in the HTML as if it would stop a regex like <span id="ResultWrapper" class="result__wrapper x5gtp_rrjnk rwekk"><b class="xus krewr"><sup>name: <span>London</span></sup></b>....... the code they use makes no sense apart from if they were trying to stop someone using very specific regex to exract something when you would use very lose expressions to handle junk as they are adding, do u hav a link to a quality article on creating own exceptions as I dont want to google n follow a fools guide etc?

Comment: So thanks for ur answer I just didn't know if you cud create custom exceptions and how. Ur right about the results for the Match, Count, IsSuccess etc, and that is what I use at the moment all the time its just one part where they change the HTML: all the time that I have to go through 4 regexes to try each one to return the results I want, if one returns no results I have to go to the next then the next. I just wanted a way if the 1st one, most common to find matches suddenly broke as their html had changed I could be notified asap by pos throwing a custom exception & how I would do that

Comment: Again, ***post code***. Someone might be able to help you if you start from that, maybe see a pattern that makes it so you don't have to write multiple regexes. You've left everyone in the dark here, unable to give you concrete help. Stop making things hard for yourself.

Comment: as I said I would hav to spend hours writing a custom example when the question is just how to create a custom exception on an error say when IsMatch returns FALSE, that is all. Everyone knows that bit of regex so if you had a try/catch around it all and I wanted a specific branch for FALSE to do something different in, how would I do it. I am not going to write custom code for examples. and I don;t know if you hv ever tried but code longer than a cetrtain amount cannot be posted in the question box here anyway so if I had copied it it wouldnt have saved anyway

Comment: Joke - sorry I should have said I was from UK

Comment: found a good example on MS site, seems pretty easy to derive a custom exception class  from the base Exception class e.g public class RegExIsBroken : Exception { } with the standard interfaces for innerException,messsage, thanks for ur help seems overkill for what I need to be honest but at least I know how to do it and its not hard. I bet you will find if you dig under many "object" parsing classes that parse XML, HTML etc that there will be a string parser deep at the bottom doing the grunt work, hiding it all with an easy XML.Parse(xml); function top level